# Dynamic range with offset (skipping lines) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for some help constructing a dynamic range formula that can skip rows.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(H111;5;0;COUNTA(H111:H116) + 1;1))
```

My idea was to start at H111 and move down 5 rows, use COUNTA to count all non-blank rows and add 1 to adjust for one blank *title/colored* row in between.

What I want to do is, is to be able to SUM all the accumulated amortizations for every asset in the total amortization cost field and to be able to add new items which the formula dynamically responds to.

Help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

With added tax rate
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=SUMIF($A$106:$A$10000,"Accumulated amortization",$H$106:$H$10000)
```

You may need to adjust the `10000` to reflect the lowest possible row, but the range can be significantly larger than the used range.

One problem with `OFFSET` is that it is volatile and, depending on the complexity of your entire worksheet, may add significantly to execution times.

Another issue with `OFFSET` is that, even if you do use it to generate an array of results, it requires further manipulation before you can effectively use those results in formulas.

Comment: This works great. Thank you! Can I bother you with one more thing? What would the function be to do the same, but to multiply each row with its corresponding tax rate? I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Svedr I would use a variation of `SUMPRODUCT` for that.  If you can't figure it out on your own, I suggest you post a separate question, and include, either as a markdown table in the question, or a link to an Excel file you have uploaded to some public sharing site, sufficient data to reconstruct a proper example.